# Partial view not serializing in ajax Post request MVC

Tags: razor, serialization, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

Implementing the auto save functionality for my page. so after certain interval calling action `Autosave()`. But my page having begin form including the Partial view. The code for after interval call is working fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setInterval(function () {       
        var form = $("#addpost");
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AutoSavePostAction", "MyControllerName")',
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#Id").val(data);
            }
        });
    }, 30000);
```

View is :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SavePostAction", "MyControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id="addpost" }))
{
    .................
    @Html.Partial("_TextPostPartial", Model);
    .................
}
```

`SavePostAction` is after calling submit. On this submission, getting the value from Partial view, which is not an issue.
But in ajax call somehow partial view does not included in serialization. 
Here `_TextPostPartial` having CKEditor which is strongly bind with Model.
Like Partial view having :

```
<textarea id="Description" name="Description">@Html.Raw(Model.Description)</textarea>
```

**Edited:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AutoSavePostAction(PostDTO postDTO, FormCollection postFormCollection)
{
}

[HttpPost]
[MemberFunction]
public ActionResult SavePostAction(PostDTO postDTO, FormCollection postFormCollection)
 {
 }
```

Comment: Is it only the `Model.Description` which is not binding in the `AutoSavePostAction()` method? Is the property decorated with `[AllowHtml]`? You should also show the signature of both controller methods.

Comment: Oh..forgot to add. Please review question. And Yes only Model.Description is not showing value

Comment: Why on earth do you have a parameter for `FormCollection`? The difference between the 2 methods is the one that working has a `[MemberFunction]` filter attribute. What does it do?

Comment: Yes purposely, [MemberFunction] its for membership regarding. And  FormCollection is for some radio buttons logic. I think its should not matter for the actual problem.

Comment: Well `[MemberFunction]` is the only difference in the signatures suggesting it could be a problem. And `FormCollection` should not be required unless your view is badly designed. You should debug your script - what does `var data = form.serialize();` return - does it contain a name/vale pair for `Description`?

Comment: Ummm... [MemberFunction] is not an issue. I tried with adding and removing it to AutoSavePostAction(). Let me alert form.serialize()

Comment: Its generating '&Description=&g-recaptcha-response=' for description. :(

Comment: As I verified the response, Description is the CKEditor which is bind with Description field. it is generating IFrame in response and setting display non for actual text area....

Comment: Include your script for how you bind to the textarea. I suspect you need `for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances ) { CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement(); }` in the script before the ajax call

Comment: Thanks, Stephen Muecke. What I did,  $("#Description").val(CKEDITOR.instances['Description'].getData());    i s working for me.

Comment: Good. Consider adding an answer and accepting it for the benefit of others :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the value of the CKEditor to the input before serializing the form data

```
 window.setInterval(function () {     
    $("#Description").val(CKEDITOR.instances['Description'].getData()); // add this
    var form = $("#addpost");
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AutoSavePostAction", "MyControllerName")',
        data: form.serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#Id").val(data);
        }
    });
}, 30000);
```

Comment: See No waste of time... worthful ;)